# Is .Net Core much slower than .Net Framework in SQL connection?

Tags: .net, .net-core, ado.net, .net-framework-version, sqlclient

Running code in .NET Core to connect to a SQL Server database seems much slower than in the full .NET Framework. Is this the case? Or I am doing something wrong?

I have SQL Server 2017 on my PC and want to run a simple stored procedure like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE OneRowSelect
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1
END
GO
```

I use SQL Client 4.6.0 to connect to the database, and get the result of this procedure in my code. So I wrote a .Net Standard 2.0 library that provides this code:

```
private const string connectionString = @"data source=.;initial catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
private const string command = @"OneRowSelect";

public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Execute()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(command, con)
        {
            CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        })
        {
            con.Open();
            var data = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

            while (data.Read())
            {
                var res = data[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I wrote two projects in .NET Core 2.2 and .NET Framework 4.7.2 and referenced this .NET Standard library in these two projects and log the execution time of `Execute` function with `Stopwatch`.

My code in these two projects is:

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

for (int i = 0; i < repeat; i++)
    await Runner.Execute();
stopwatch.Stop();
```

The result was unbelievable. .NET Core is much slower than .NET Framework in my system. The results are:

- .NET Framework average running time: **2.2ms**
- .NET Core average running time: **36.7ms**

Am I wrong or is .NET Core this much slower than the .NET Framework?

Comment: Did you call this method just once, or repeatedly? (If you measure a single timing, there are all *kinds* of things that can affect it. Ideally, use Benchmark.NET to do this properly.) Have you tried the same kind of test with a *useful* query/SP rather than a no-op one?

Comment: I run this method 100 times and got an average(also I repeat this test multiple time). Yes, I have tested this with exact database that fetch some ids of my table and I have seen some results like this

Comment: It may be worth looking at some potential differences like whether .NET Core is using TCP/IP and .NET Framework is using named pipes. I don't know whether that's the case, but *forcing* them to use the same transport would at least be an interesting start. I very much doubt that this is about the CLR itself.

Comment: Can you check, if the performance get's better, if you remove the async calling? Then it might be connected to [this](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/27769) issue.

Comment: OK. I have just removed the async calls and test it again. The results of .Net-Framework becomes 4.2 and .Net-Core becomes 18.4 which is also much slower than .Net-Framework

Comment: @AminMirzaee How come you are not doing await conn.OpenAsync() and await reader.ReadAsync(). You have a mish-mash of synchronous and async code.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras You were right. I should have used Async in all of my code, however it wouldn't changed the result after another test

Comment: Did you try running a single `Runner.Execute()` before the Stopwatch based benchmark? (maybe there is some internal warm-up code that's slower on first call to improve calls afterwards)

Comment: @hiiru I have done what you want and the result didn't changed